# valgrind 3.6.0 crashes on Mac OS X Server 10.6.6

Tags: valgrind

Valgrind 3.6.0 crashes upon launch under Mac OS X Server 10.6.6. Here is the crash log:

```
Process:         valgrind [958]
Path:            /usr/local/Cellar/valgrind/3.6.0/bin/valgrind
Identifier:      valgrind
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  bash [953]

Date/Time:       2011-03-07 19:35:13.144 +0100
OS Version:      Mac OS X Server 10.6.6 (10J567)
Report Version:  6

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000134000000
Crashed Thread:  Unknown

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x000000000000000e  rbx: 0x0000000134000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000134000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000138424ab0  rsp: 0x0000000138424aa0
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x000000013803f03a  rfl: 0x0000000000010206  cr2: 0x0000000134000000

Binary images description not available
```

The Mac OS X Server kernel runs in 32-bit mode.

valgrind 3.6.0 runs fine on the non-server version of Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug in the build process of valgrind when using the linker that is installed with Xcode 4.0.1.

See [bug report](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=267997).